# Netbeans+PHP+readline: no prompt string

Tags: php, netbeans, readline

I am using Netbeans to develop PHP console application samples (just for fun and proof of concept). [readline](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readline.php) is a library binding that takes a string from the console. For example, be `read.php` a file with the following content:

```php
<?php
$line = readline("Name: ");
echo "$line\n";
?>
```

I can execute it as (gnome-terminal + bash)

```
php read.php
```

And it will outputs like

```
Name: Firstname Lastname
Firstname Lastname
```

So far so good.

When I put this code inside Netbeans, the console also inside Netbeans, it does not echo the prompt "Name: ". For example, this is a screenshot took after SHIFT+F6 pressed [image: Sample screenshot]

Any insights towards how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

According to an answer in [Trying to read from the console in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26470972/trying-to-read-from-the-console-in-java) IDEs don't normally provide a valid TTY which is required for this to work.

What you could do instead is create a helper function such as this:

```
function readlineHelper(?string $prompt = null): string|false
{
    if ($propmpt)
    {
        echo $prompt;
    }

    return readline();
}
```